# Where 'prebuilts' in AOSP are comming from?

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to port Android SDK Tools to unsupported system (OpenBSD for that matter).
I've already fixed few things in go scripts for 'lunch' to work.
Now I'm at the point where I need to provide binaries to actually build SDK for current machine.

Some of the tools are provided inside AOSP.
There are bunch of prebuilt executables and libraries inside `prebuilts/build-tools/` in `linux-x86` and `darwin-x86` subdirs for specific platforms.

Question is, how did they get there?
There are `aidl`, `m4`, `ninja`, `soong_zip`, `zipalign`, etc.
I could link some of them from base system but for some of them (`soong_zip`, for example) I didn't find any information how to obtain them.
Is there some kind of google repo where one can build them from?

Any information that could be relevant to the topic are also will be welcomed.